# Temporal weights, unequal length of time series, how to align?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, keras

I have time series of unequal length that I feed into a RNN-LSTM created in keras. My understanding is that if I choose sample_weight_mode='temporal' the network will learn a different set of weights for every time step. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

I guess that the first time step of every time series will be handled by one set of weights, the second step of every series by another set and so on. Accordingly, the last step of the longest time series will get a different set of weights than the last step of the shortest time series. How can I get the same set of weights for the last step of every series?

Viewed differently: I believe that all the time series are left-aligned when using sample_weight_mode='temporal' whereas I would like to have them right-aligned. How could I achieve that?

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: @Loopo I'm sorry but I don't know exactly what you mean.